# List all spreadsheets using a Google Sheets API

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use the Google Sheets API with PHP to list all spreadsheets in user X account whose file name matches certain pattern, for instance "company_abc_052017_en". Is this possible with Google Sheets API and PHP?

Thanks,
Z

Answer (score 0):

If the spreadsheets are located in your Google Drive, you can certainly fetch all spreadsheets using [File.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) using the [queries](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) where you search for MiMEType of type

```
 application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet
```

If you're doing this using Sheetsv4 API per se, there is no method to do this, unlike in Sheets v3 where it had:

```
GET https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full
```